# PHP array only showing last product within json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a shopping cart and once the action placeorder.php is hit, i have set-up a webhook to post to discord.

The cart uses session arrays to store the cart information.

the session array is set as below on the product.php page when the "add to card" button is pressed

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array($product_id => $quantity);
```

The product IDs are pulled from a mysql DB.

**With 2x items added to the cart, the array is as follows:**

```
 ["cart"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=> int(5)
    [4]=> int(3)
  }
```

**If I echo the array it comes out as**

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    echo $product[name];
    echo $products_in_cart[$product['id']];
}


Output: camera5laptop3

$products_in_cart[$product['id'] is simply grabbing the quantity ordered.
```

**The JSON Structure**

I am trying to make it so that every product name in the cart appears on a new line (\n) under the "Ordered Products" field. and the same for the quanity.

This would be through a foreach but since the json structure is within json_encode() I am struggling.

The below set-up **currently only** shows the **last** *$product['name']* and *$products_in_cart[$product['id']* in the array

```
$msg = json_encode([
    // Message
    "content" => "",
 
    // Username
    //"username" => "",
 
    // Avatar URL.
    // Uncomment to use custom avatar instead of bot's pic
    //"avatar_url" => "",
 
    // text-to-speech
    "tts" => false,
 
    // file_upload
    // "file" => "",
    // Embeds Array
    
    "embeds" => [
        [
            // Title
            "title" => "New Order",
 
            // Embed Type, do not change.
            "type" => "rich",
 
            // Description
            "description" => "New order, go sort it",
 
            // Link in title
            //"url" => "",
 
            // Timestamp, only ISO8601
            "timestamp" => $timestamp,
 
            // Left border color, in HEX
            "color" => hexdec( "3366ff" ),
 
            // Footer text
            "footer" => [
                "text" => "Sent from thestash.store",
                "icon_url" => ""
            ],
 
            // Embed image
            "image" => [
                "url" => ""
            ],
 
            // thumbnail
            //"thumbnail" => [
            //    "url" => ""
            //],
 
            // Author name & url
            "author" => [
                "name" => "TEST3",
                "url" => ""
            ],
 
            // Custom fields

            "fields" => [
                // Field 1
                
                [
                    "name" => "Ordered Products",
                    "value" => $product['name'],
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                // Field 2
                 // Field 1
                 [
                    "name" => "Quantity",
                    "value" => $products_in_cart[$product['id']],
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Order Total $",
                    "value" => $subtotal,
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Customer Alias",
                    "value" => $_SESSION['alias'],
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Customer Number",
                    "value" => $_SESSION['number'],
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Affiliation",
                    "value" => $_SESSION['affiliation'],
                    "inline" => true
                ],

                // etc
            ]
        ]
    ]

], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Current Output on discord:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dEPPCOk.png]

Attempting to output as (manuall set in JSON)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/QBNJuLH.png]

**print_r($msg);**

```
{
    "content": "",
    "tts": false,
    "embeds": [
        {
            "title": "New Order",
            "type": "rich",
            "description": "New order, go sort it",
            "timestamp": "2023-01-13T11:57:22+00:00",
            "color": 3368703,
            "footer": {
                "text": "Sent from thestash.store",
                "icon_url": ""
            },
            "image": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "author": {
                "name": "TEST3",
                "url": "https://thestash.store"
            },
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "Ordered Products",
                    "value": "laptop",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Quantity",
                    "value": 3,
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Order Total $",
                    "value": 96000
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer Alias",
                    "value": "quigg",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer Number",
                    "value": "1239871237378127",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Affiliation",
                    "value": "yes",
                    "inline": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Attempting to have the JSON format as follows. Where each $product[name] and $products_in_cart[$product['id']] is on a new line. Currently the last $product[name] and $products_in_cart[$product['id']] show

```
{
    "content": "",
    "tts": false,
    "embeds": [
        {
            "title": "New Order",
            "type": "rich",
            "description": "New order, go sort it",
            "timestamp": "2023-01-13T11:57:22+00:00",
            "color": 3368703,
            "footer": {
                "text": "Sent from thestash.store",
                "icon_url": ""
            },
            "image": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "author": {
                "name": "TEST3",
                "url": "https://thestash.store"
            },
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "Ordered Products",
                    "value": "camera\nlaptop",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Quantity",
                    "value": "5\n3",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Order Total $",
                    "value": 96000
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer Alias",
                    "value": "quigg",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer Number",
                    "value": "1239871237378127",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Affiliation",
                    "value": "yes",
                    "inline": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It might be simpler to understand what you are asking if you added a simple 1) What are the Inputs. 2) What I want the output to look like. 3) What I tried. 4) What I got. Then we may be able to help

Comment: It's very unclear also because you appear to be echoing `$product["id"]` but none of the arrays you've shown have an "id" property. And it's unclear how your foreach loop relates to your JSON thing, the whole question is incoherent. Remember we can't see your screen or read your mind. Look back on it and see if you think someone who had never encountered your app or data before would make head or tail of what you're trying to do or where the difficulty is, without having a proper [mre] of the issue or any relevant data, or a clear problem description with examples. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: In theory, translating an array into JSON is as simple as passing it to json_encode(). You seem to be trying to build a static array for some reason, which also doesn't make sense, but as RiggsFolly says we can't see the source datasets, or a clear representation of the expected output, so it's very difficult to suggest a sensible solution. P.S. You can [edit] your post to update it. If you tried something with a loop, please show it and explain the exact problem. "struggle" isn't an error message or a clear problem statement, so we can't help with that either.

Comment: ill update now to give a clear idea of what im trying to acheive and ill include more of the code to help picture what im trying to achieve

Comment: loop over the products array and do it like this: `foreach ($products as $product){ $system["cart"][] =  $product;}`. It's a sample example so check and change variable names accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's starting to make more sense But, as opposed to pictures of end-user output in the application, which isn't particularly helpful, please show the actual JSON you're trying to create with the code (i.e. presumably, the JSON you created manually).

Comment: so the only json is within the jsonencode() shown above. There is no seperate json. (This is my first project that is not just html+css). Would parsing the PHP session array to a json array allow more feasability of what im attempting to achieive?

Comment: 1) that isn't JSON, it's a PHP array...you haven't shown us any JSON at all. json_encode _outputs_ JSON but you haven't shown it. But 2) What I asked for was the JSON you said you created manually, which then produces the result you wanted in discord. The aim of the PHP code is to output the correct JSON, isn't it? So then, please show us the expected output, in JSON format.

Comment: Ok so your second product does not appear to be in that JSON. Do a `print_r($msg);` after that json_encode **which should be a `json_decode();`** so we can see actaul data without all those noisey comments

Comment: ___BIG NOTE___ There is an unwritten rule with JSON! NEVER try and write it manually. Always build a Object/Array/DataStructure in the format you want the data and then use `json_encode()` to turn it into valid JSON.

Comment: So that's the JSON it produces currently. You still haven't told us what JSON you _want_ instead...remember we don't necessarily know what Discord requires you to send in order to create the output in your screenshot. You need to have a clear idea in your mind of what the final JSON needs to look like (you should have tested it manually against the API to make it do what you need) so that you can then write some code to achieve it. If you show us what you actually want, in JSON format, then we can more easily help you to do it. That's what we've been saying the entire time on this thread.

Comment: Ok i get ya, appreciate the guidance so far. pretty new to this side of things. I've added the ideal JSON format. Let me know if you need me to adjust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's just a case of adding extra things into two strings, separated by newlines. So just loop over the products array to create two strings, one for the name and one for the quantity, and put those into variables. Then, you can just use those variables in the right places in your Fields array.

Heres the general idea:

```
$names = "";
$quantities = "";

foreach ($products as $product){
    $names .= ($names != "" ? "\n" : "").$product["name"];
    $quantities .= ($quantities != "" ? "\n" : "").$products_in_cart[$product['id']];
}
```

Then in the bit where you build the array:

```
...
"fields" => [
                [
                    "name" => "Ordered Products",
                    "value" => $names,
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Quantity",
                    "value" => $quantities,
                    "inline" => true
                ],
...
```

Comment: That did the trick! thanks for the help here. Really appreciate it :)